# File IO tricks using c/c++

Tags: c++, c

Are there some good books or articles about file processing with c/c++, especially when the file is very large, GB or something like that?

Comment: What are the problems you encounter. Reading large files as a stream is no problem, any recent C implementation of the stdio has large file support. It is probably more what you want to do with the data in the file, that won't fit in memory, or not? What kind of operations do you want to do with that data?

Comment: There is no such thing like C/C++, these are two different languages. And in particular the concepts for IO are quite orthogonal between the two.

Comment: @Jens: Agreed. Thios warrants a `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but it's hard to imagine what issues you're concerned about, and you don't state your OS/filesystem.  You should check your OS documentation to see whether the usual fopen() et al are already or have 64 bit versions, your compiler docs for any command line switches or issues with std::fstream support of large files.  You should also consider memory mapping the files, and - to ensure the operating system supports you as well as possible with unnecessary adverse affect on other processes - whether it accepts any hints from your application about the style of access you plan to do on the file (i.e. random access vs sequential access).

So, from these three approaches: fopen et all, fstream, mmap - write a little program and test each... it'll take you a few hours and you'll learn a lot.